# Our maid is not allowing to work another maid

Tags: difficult-people, bangladesh

In Dhaka-Bangladesh, person, mostly women, worked as a maid. They worked for 2 hours approximately. Each day they work in many houses.

One maid also works for us and her work is not good. We want to change maid. That's why we search and found many maids who agreed to work. As it's not possible to measure new maid's working quality without giving then work or see them working, we are allowing both of them to work in our house in different time. If new one works good, then we will say no to old one. But, only working for 1 day every maid decline to work ( even if we offer them extra money) After that, new maids do not pick up calls! To know the truth, we called them several times. FYI, we found 7 new maids in 45 days. After talking They all have common. Everyone says that their husbands are not allowing to work. And they have talked to our old maid.

What's the reason? Why do they not want to work here? I strongly believe that our old maid told them something bad about us or not to work here. FYI, our old maid is an angry person.

1) We behave very respectfully with them 2) All of our maids live within 500 meters. We go to those place and search new maid by asking people if anyone know someone who wants to work. 3) I strongly believe that old one does not want to lose her job. She already knows that we are about to say no to her. 4) Here, maids have a good network. They keep words to each other. I am not the only one in Dhaka who facing this problem. 5) Talked with several persons (approx 20 in Dhaka) and found 5 of them faced these issue. How can I get out of this syndicate?

About the number 5, All of them live in a rented house. 3 of them solved this issue by complaining land owner. 2 of them can't solve the problem. FYI, I live in my own house.

Comment: Ever wondered if you (as well as other people) pay them what their work is worth? Or what they think it's worth? Might be only a matter of money here? i.e. they want to get more money, but still keep their job, and not sharing time with another maid?

Comment: In this situation, obviously agreed to their price. Most importantly, I offer all of new ones extra money.

There is a syndicate going one. We are helpless and annoyed too.

Comment: I hope somebody won't decide this is *not* an interpersonal question, @OldPadawan, because it really has intriguing inter-personal aspects within a social, cultural and work-related setting. Of course only somebody who is really familiar with the specific culture could give an expert solution but I expect some very good common-sense answers such as the first one posted here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am not at all familiar with the local culture in Bangladesh, so this answer doesn't consider any cultural nuances.*

This sounds to me like it's a case of professional courtesy between the maids. You say that all of the maids you have talked to have also talked to your current maid. They probably don't want to go work somewhere that would cause someone they know to get fired, the flip side being that your maid would give them the same courtesy. Additionally, you are only offering them one day's worth of work, so they have no incentive to damage their own personal and professional relationships for just a *chance* of getting work.

There are a couple things that might help your situation. First, you will likely have to offer your new maid full time upfront - no trial day. This guarantees them a job rather than making it just an interview. If you are worried about the quality of their work, ask them for references from other clients they have worked with, or ask your friends to refer you to maids they like. You might still get people refusing to work for you because of your current maid, so you may need to fire her before you hire someone new.

You also mention that all of the maids live within 500 meters of each other, and that's how you find them. You may need to find another location in order to find someone who doesn't know your current maid. If your maid really is spreading lies about you, then you will either need to find someone who doesn't know her or find someone trusted who can vouch for you to them.

Comment: +1 for a very good, common-sense answer that makes some *very* pertinent points and also gives OP fresh angles to approach the problem.